# Reactive join across 3 subsciptions in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have the following collections:
1. Users
2. Messages
3. Meta

I want to grab all the unique autor properties from the Messages and Meta collection. Then I want to subscribe to all the data about those users. So it's something like this:

```
var ids = [];

Messages.find().forEach(function(doc) {
 ids.push(doc.author);
});

var allIds = ids.concat( Meta.findOne().authors );

Meteor.subscribe('contactInfo', _.uniq(allIds) );
```

The question is how to do all this at a router level so that all the subscriptions load before the page is rendered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor.publish: publish collection which depends on other collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398952/meteor-publish-publish-collection-which-depends-on-other-collection)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna create relations between subscriptions this package will do the trick

[Publish with relations](https://atmospherejs.com/cottz/publish-with-relations)