# How to filter a meteor cursor after the query and then publish the result

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I’m trying to meteor publish only documents that a user has access to.
The access system is outside of the document database but a function call like hasAccess(customuserID, _id) will return true if the user has access.

The problem is that publish returns a cursor so I can’t do something like:

```
Meteor.publish('theInvoices', function () {
  return Invoices.find().fetch().filter(function (doc) {
    return hasAccess(customerUserID, doc._id); // external access , filter
  });
});
```

Or course this functions returns an array of filtered documents and not a cursor so the question is how do I filter the results of query (without using database filters) before publishing the results or how do I turn an array of documents into a publishable cursor?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```js
Meteor.publish('theInvoices', function () {
  var invoices = Invoices.find().fetch().filter(function (doc) {
    return hasAccess(customerUserID, doc._id);
  });
  var invoiceIds = _.pluck(invoices, '_id');
  return Invoices.find({_id: {$in: invoiceIds}});
});
```

That just finds all of the allowed invoice ids, and published a new cursor based on that list. Keep in mind this [isn't reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398952/meteor-publish-publish-collection-which-depends-on-other-collection).

Also note that `customerUserID` should be defined somewhere.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a solution to make it reactive?

Comment: The easiest solution is to add an array of user ids with access to each invoice document. Then you can just add that information to the selector.

Comment: Missed your link before, that helps.  Thanks again.

Comment: to make it reactive, you could use https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish that allow autorun on server