# Meteor publish out of date

Tags: meteor, collections, publish

On my server side, I publish a `Groups` collection. This relies on publishing groups that match another `Servers` collection.

```
Meteor.publish('groups', function() {   
    const servers = Servers.find({}); // simplified code
    return Groups.find({serverId: {$in: servers}});
});
```

A client view then subscribes to that:

```
self.autorun(() => {
    self.subscribe('groups');
});
```

This generally works fine. The problem comes when I add insert a server in the `Servers` collections, there is no indication to the publication to update the Groups, therefore this added server's `Groups` don't publish to the client.

What is the right way to handle this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167667/inconsistent-updating-of-meteor-template/43183145#43183145 => look for server side _reactive_ publication

Answer (score 0):

The Meteor Guide is always a good starting point for these kind of problems. Go here https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publishing-relations. TLDR; just add reywood:publish-composite package. :)

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A possible straightforward approach here is to create a separate publication for `Servers` and then make `groups` `Servers`-dependent.

```js
// Server
Meteor.publish("servers", function() {
  return Servers.find({}, { fields: { _id: 1 } });
});

Meteor.publish("groups", function(serversIds) {
  return Groups.find({ serverId: { $in: serversIds } });
});

// Client
self.autorun(() => {
  self.subscribe("servers");
});

self.autorun(() => {
  const serversIds = Servers.find().map(server => server._id);
  self.subscribe("groups", serversIds);
});
```