# Meteor MongoDB Filter Parent Records by Child Fields

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, meteor, nosql

How would I go about filtering a set of records based on their child records.

Let's say I have a collection `Item` that has a field to another collection `Bag` called `bagId`. I'd like to find all `Items` where a field on `Bags` matches some clause.

I.e. `db.Items.find( { "where bag.type:'Paper' " })` . How would I go about doing this in MongoDB. I understand I'd have to `join` on Bags and then link where `Item.bagId == Bag._id`

I used Studio3T to convert a SQL `GROUP BY` to a Mongo aggregate. I'm just wondering if there's any defacto way to do this.

1. Should I perform a data migration to simply include `Bag.type` on every `Item` document (don't want to get into the habit of continuously making schema changes everytime I want to sort/filter `Items` by `Bag` fields).
2. Use something like https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate (No luck with that syntax yet)
3. Grapher https://github.com/cult-of-coders/grapher I played around with this briefly and while it's cool I'm not sure if it'll actually solve my problem. I can use it to add `Bag.type` to every Item returned, but I don't see how that could help me filter every item by `Bag.type`.

Is this just one of the tradeoffs of using a NoSQL dbms? What option above is recommended or are there any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: So do you wanted to pass word `paper` to bags collection get respective doc & respective sorted items docs based on `_id` of retrieved doc from bags ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meteor.publish: publish collection which depends on other collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398952/meteor-publish-publish-collection-which-depends-on-other-collection)

Comment: @ChristianFritz I'm actually already using PublishComposite. It does help with getting a `join` of my data. Thing is `Item` is my top level document and `Bags` are `children` so I can't filter the top-level documents by `children` fields. So I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [$in functionality](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)  of MongoDB. It would look something like this:

`const bagsIds = Bags.find({type: 'paper'}, {fields: {"_id": 1}}).map(function(bag) { return bag._id; });
const items = Items.find( { bagId: { $in: bagsIds } } ).fetch();`

It would take some testing if the reactivity of this solution is still how you expect it to work and if this would still be suitable for larger collections instead of going for your first solution and performing the migration.

Comment: This could work. Caveat is that I need to run two fetches. First get `bags` and then `Items`. But might be fine because I'm publishing paginated records